# Master data services authentication through url

Tags: master-data-services

I'm new to Master data Services (MDS) and I would like to know if it is possible to authenticate MDS through url. The reason why I'm asking is we have a web application which contains a link to the MDS and we would like to connect to MDS with the credentials of the user currently logged in to our web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to the MDS web application.  The user clicking the link will need access to MDS in order to view the MDS web application.  You can also use leverage the WCF service that comes with MDS to integrate MDS functionality into an app.